# Reset Viewport Zoom on iOS10 with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios10, viewport

I have a page that I need to reset the viewport scale (the pinch zoom) on command, setting it back to the initial zoomed out state.

Looks like the old tried and true method of rewriting the meta viewport:

```
const viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
viewport.attr('content', "initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0");
```

doesn't seem to have any effect anymore on ios10 (page remains zoomed in). Is there any way around this?

**Update**

.attr is a jquery method, my mistake for leaving that in the original question (supposed to be setAttribute I was trying a bunch of different things to make this work). The issue still stands though.

On iOS 10+ zoom in really far, like this:

[image]

Changing the viewport when you've zoomed past device width doesn't zoom back out when viewport meta tag is changed. This *does* work on android (at least in the chrome browser).

Comment: Does this page already contain the meta tag of name viewport?

Comment: @Mattcoady check the answer and let me know if you have any problem

Comment: @SagarV no, that didn't work. I've set up a test page here (with your snippet): http://mattcoady.me/test.html Pinch zoom in really far and click the button. The viewport does not zoom back out to device-width. I've added more details in my edit above.

Comment: @MattCoady are you sure you want to allow the user to zoom in?

Comment: None of the above answers worked for my case (dealing with iOS zoom triggered by focussing on an input field). My breakthrough came by finding [this post](http://blog.osmosys.asia/2017/01/05/prevent-ios-from-zooming-in-on-input-fields/#comment-586). Solution #3 was simple and appropriate for my needs: by adding `font-size: 16px;` to the tags `body` and my input field, I prevented iOS from auto-zooming in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Issues

1. `attr()` is not a JavaScript function. It is a jQuery method.
2. you are using `viewportmeta` to get the `meta` tag and then try to set attribute to `viewport` variable, which is not declared.

### Solution

Since you are using JavaScript, use the `setAttribute` method instead.

Syntax :

```
const viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]');
viewportmeta.setAttribute('content', "initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0");
```

Snippet

```js
let viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');

viewportmeta.setAttribute('content', "initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0");
console.log(document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]'));
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" />
```

It will set the `content` on if the `meta[name=viewport]` is present in the page.

If you don't have a `<meta name="viewport".../>` in the page, create one, use `setAttribute` to set `name=viewport` and append it to head.

Working Snippet

```js
let viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
if(viewportmeta===null){
  viewportmeta = document.createElement("meta");
  viewportmeta.setAttribute("name","viewport");
  document.head.appendChild(viewportmeta);
  
  viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]');
}
viewportmeta.setAttribute('content', "initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0");
console.log(document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]'));
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. I built a test page here: http://mattcoady.me/test.html Open it on iOS 10 (I'm using 10.2) and pinch zoom in really far (example: https://i.imgur.com/OOvygyd.png). Triggering the viewport change when you've pinch-zoomed in past device width doesn't do anything. I need it to return to device-width.

Comment: @MattCoady you want to return to the default zoom level when trigger viewport change. same as we load the page first. right ?

Comment: So I found the issue. Looks like the xcode iOS device simulator and the real devices handle viewport differently. Looks like your code worked all along on a real device. :/ Feels like a bit of an oversight on Apples part. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Also, I found that setting the value of meta viewport content, it only has any effect **only once**. If you try to zoom out multiple times, you might need to apply **random values**.

```
    function pinchOut() {
        appliedScale = 1 - Math.random()*0.01;
        document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]').setAttribute('content', "width=device-width, initial-scale=" + appliedScale);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to go to the default zoom level as the page has when load it first use below snippet.

```
const viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]');
viewportmeta.setAttribute('content', "width=device-width, initial-scale=0");
```

This will set the default zoom and let your user zoom in again if he wants.
I checked this in my iPhone 6/iOS 10

Comment: Note : you can also adjust minimum-scale=value, from 0 to 1 as per your need. like minimum-scale=0.30. set it where it suits you zoom need on device.

Comment: I've found the issue. Looks like the xcode iOS device simulator and the real devices handle viewport differently. This code works on real devices. I awarded the bounty to Sagar since they gave a working answer first. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Great. you fixed it. this is all we wanted.