# Javascript to reset mobile viewport zoom level

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, viewport

I have a site where mobile users often zoom in on photos which is very much intended.  However, I have a need to reset the zoom when certain links are accessed or specific javascript events fire.  Specifically targeting mobile Safari.

Please note:

- Various solutions to read `meta[name="viewport"]` and then set its content are ignored by mobile Safari.  Maybe that worked years ago, but it doesn't now.

The best idea I've have so far that works for links is to point them all to a different domain (which does reset the viewport) and then have that domain instantly redirect back to my site.  I'd pass the actual intended URL as a GET param.  I tested it and it works, but sheesh.  It also only helps for links, I want to be able to do it for javascript events where there is no navigation taking place.

Comment: how bout this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44599800/reset-viewport-zoom-on-ios10-with-javascript

Comment: why dont use scale or zoom property instead? https://caniuse.com/css-zoom. so only the image that zoomed when the pinch event fired.

Comment: @Rumeee The accepted solution in that thread (from 2017 for iOS 10) doesn't work anymore.